# Silverlight 4 - use StaticResource from one ResourceDictionary in another

Tags: silverlight, resourcedictionary, staticresource

**If I have these dictionaries:**

dict1.xaml:
`<Color x:Key="Color1">Red</Color>`

dict2.xaml:
`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush1" Color={StaticResource Color1} />`

**This works:**

App.xaml:

```
<MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="dict1.xaml"/>
<MergedDictionaries>
```

SomePage.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="dict2.xaml"/>
  </MergedDictionaries>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**This does not:**

App.xaml merging both at application level.

I get an error about Color1 not being found.

Why is this ? / Is there a way around it? I know this example is simplistic, but a real one would be too long. Basically I'm just trying to organize my styles and templates in different files:

- One for colors
- One for implicit styles
- Many for explicit styles

edit: curiously, if I do this in code on `Application_Startup`, before setting the `RootVisual` property, I don't get the error... I'm just perplexed as to why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you've run into an annoying limitation in the Silverlight resources system which I can only imagine is some optimization issue.  There seems to be some asynchronous behaviour here where each dictionary in `MergedDictionaries` are loaded in parallel, hence when "dict2.xaml" is loading you cannot rely on content of "dict1.xaml" being present.

The simplest solution is to include the merging of Dict1 in Dict2:-

App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="dict2.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Dict2.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="dict1.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    .... <!-- dict2 resource -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="dict1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="dict2.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

as long as you are defining the dictionary before the  other one I am a little suprised something similar to the above wouldn't work.

Comment: I already tried that before posting this as that would be the obvious culprit. However, no such luck. It seems to be trying to resolve then simultaneously, which is just ridiculously infuriating to me because I can't see a single case where you WANT that behavior, especially if MS doesn't give us `DynamicResource`

Comment: it may be helpful to see your app.xaml as you have it when its failing. I have done this myself and can't see or think of anything special I had to do to get it to work

Comment: That's all my App xaml has aside from the declaration of the file (stuff I didn't touch).

When you say you've done this, did you have dictionaries where one references a resource that is defined in another? Because literally, I have reproduced this in a completely new project with NOTHING else in it except the two dicts, mergeddictionaries, and one page with one textblock using a style in one of the dictionaries (though I don't think it gets that far)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a way proposed by @Anthony but there is one caveat here - if you use your 1st resource dictionary in, for example, 5 other dictionaries then it will be loaded 5 times and you'll have 6 copies of the same resource dictionary (it's in case when you referenced it in App.xaml) which is not very good for performance. This can be fixed using small subclass of silverlight's resource dictionary from here - http://softnotes.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/shared-resourcedictionary-for-silverlight/ .

Answer (score 0):

I'm with tam on this one.  "The resource lookup logic in the collection of merged resource dictionaries is last in, first out." In other words, if you have multiple dictionaries where one references the other then the dictionary that contains the referenced resources has to be at the top of the stack.  Make sure you are referencing them in the right order and be careful to make sure the dictionaries at the top of the stack have NO dependencies on the dictionaries at the bottom of the stack

```
<Application.Resources>         
 <ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                                     
   <ResourceDictionary Source="Dict1.xaml" /> 
   <ResourceDictionary Source="dependsOnDict1.xaml" />                   
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>         
 </ResourceDictionary>     
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: That's not the behavior exhibited. If this were the case, there would be no problem and I wouldn't have posted this question nearly a year ago. Try it and see :)